# Where are the classes and resources present earlier in tools.jar now located in JAVA 11? Is there any substitute?

Tags: java, java-8, libraries, java-11

I was working on a JAVA upgrade project(from Java 8->11) and i had removed the tools.jar from classpath when compiling with JAVA 11 and things work fine. Do i need to find any replacement for the tools.jar ?

Comment: If things are working fine, then what is the concern about? Do you find any classes missing? Just try to execute the compiled code as well and you would know.

Comment: No, you need not do anything: https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/97eff450e9edbd7d006deb35f28e3fd4, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-2C896CA8-927C-4381-A737-B1D81D964B7B